# Excel HYPERLINK function doesn't work

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I've got a spreadsheet that includes Google Map links, but the links don't work. They're generated with this function:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com/maps/place/" & F19 & "," & F20)
```

...where F19 and F20 contain lat and long coordinates in +/- format. It *appears* to work fine, produces a link and everything, but clicking on them just pops up a "An unexpected error has occurred" error.

I've googled the issue a bit, but all the solutions I've found seem to refer to earlier versions of Excel and revolve around registering old DLLs that can't be found on this system. Links automatically generated by just entering an URL in a cell also pop up the error, but simultaneously open the link properly.

Any advice?

Comment: You are a very active member of SO which is highly appreciated. Request your feedback on answer posted by me.

Comment: I can't try it until I get in to work on Monday, but I'll be sure to get back to you then. Thanks!

Comment: I have uploaded my working file for your tweaking and perusal. [Google-Maps](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tpma6uwo8sc6u9f/google_maps.xlsm?dl=0)

Comment: I work out few selected and chosen questions only and shall feel motivated, if you provide me your valuable feedback as promised.

Comment: While that is appreciated, unfortunately I was assigned other tasks yesterday and couldn't get to your suggestions until today.

Comment: Please take your own time. I am not in a hurry so long as you are seized with a problem. Thanks for your prompt response.

Comment: I have edited my Answer to cover replies to problems raised in your question. Regarding posting Google map As question and answer, I feel it will definitely get attention of members as you are a very active member of SO and surely many people may be tracking your Questions and Answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am following the following steps to Link Google Map URL's From the Excel Worksheet.

A. Analysis of URL

For example Google Map URL for India is :

```
https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/India/@20.1505368,64.4808042,4z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x30635ff06b92b791:0xd78c4fa1854213a6!8m2!3d20.593684!4d78.96288?hl=en
```

It has following distinct parts.

- a)    https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/
- b)   Place whose map is required like "India"
- c)   Location Identifier after @ For India it is

  ```
  20.1505368,64.4808042,4z
  ```
- d)   Location Data Identifier after "/data=" For India it is

  ```
  !3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x30635ff06b92b791:0xd78c4fa1854213a6!8m2!3d20.593684!4d78.96288?hl=en
  ```

  1. Now we put the respective parts in A4,B4,C4,D4 respectively.
  2. We use the following formula in E4 to concatenate the strings
     together.

     ```
          =A4 & B4 & "/@" & C4 & "/data=" & D4
     ```
  3. Finally another cell for example in E8 we use the HYPERLINK
     Formula.

     ```
     =HYPERLINK(E4,"India ")
     ```
  4. Now it is a clickable link and we can open India's Map by clicking on the link.

Finally snapshot pictorially depicts it.

[image: Snapshot showing Google Maps Hyperlink process]

**EDIT 28-06-2016**
Regarding problems raised in the question my viewpoint is mentioned against each point.

> Links automatically generated by just entering an URL in a cell also
>   pop up the error, but simultaneously open the link properly.

Regarding problem occurring when full hyperlink is entered. Other checks are to made. Is it a casual phenomenon even after clearing the cache and restarting the system or a regular one. If it persists on a new instance of excel after clearing cache( I use CCleaner free version) then problem may please be taken up with Microsoft Community

> ...where F19 and F20 contain lat and long coordinates in +/- format.
>   It appears to work fine, produces a link and everything, but clicking
>   on them just pops up a "An unexpected error has occurred" error.

This problem could have linkage with the problem mentioned above. It can also be caused  by a minor syntax problem relating to concatenation of strings. I faced similar problems relating to proper concatenation of strings of the URL and could solve it after a number of attempts in syntax correcting. Finally I found that constructing URL is easier and without much of syntax problems, If I put various elements of the URL in the cells of the worksheet and from their values construct the final URL.

Comment: That's very comprehensive, thanks. But constructing the link is the easy bit - the question was what could be causing the "An unexpected error has occurred" problem with the `HYPERLINK` functions. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Andrew Perry It could be a minor syntax problem relating to concatenation of strings. I arrived at this after a number of tries. Finally I found that constructing URL is easier and without much of syntax problems, If I put various elements of the URL in the cells of the worksheet and from their values construct the final URL. HTH

Comment: @Andrew Perry Regarding problem occurring when full hyperlink is entered. Other checks are to made. Is it a casual phenomenon even after clearing the cache and restarting the system or a regular one. If it persists on a new instance of excel after clearing cache( I use CCleaner free version) then problem may please be taken up with Microsoft Community.

Comment: Interesting. I cleared my temp files yesterday, and today it works. Ah, Windows... ;-)

Comment: Also, I'll second your endorsement of CCleaner. I've been a Piriform fan for years, marvellous stuff. :-D

Comment: @Andrew Perry Would you be kind enough to accept my answer as it seems that yours problems stand resolved. I am also feeling very happy to be associated with you in this problem.

Comment: Sure, if you'd like to move your comment about the cache and whatnot into the answer. As good as the answer is, I'd prefer to accept the answer when it refers to the question at hand.

Comment: Would probably be well worth posting your Google Map method as a self-answered question, by the way, in case anyone's looking for that.

Comment: @Andrew Perry I appreciate your decision. Thanks a lot.